# How can I get a private key for my watch only adress

Tags: blockchain

I'm new on bitcoin I have bitcoins that are stored on watch only address and I dnt have a private key for this address even when I add it to mycelium it says warning this address does not have a private key, but now the problem comes when I try to export a private key there is no option for private key from addresses I select manage and it gives this options.. Archive, transfer and spent no option for private key... Please help

Comment: welcome to bitcoin.SE! Can you tell us a bit more about your case, why do you want the private keys, and why do you want to export from Mycelium? Are these private keys belonging to addresses, that you might have from an exchange?

Answer (score 1):

> I have bitcoins that are stored on watch only address

**What are watch-only addresses?**

A watch-only address is a public bitcoin addresses you’ve imported into your wallet. This is a cool, useful feature if you want to monitor activity at a particular bitcoin address. You can import any existing bitcoin address.

There is no way to get access to those bitcoins because it's a **watch only** address. You can only watch it, but you can't do anything else (sending BTC away, exporting the private key, signing something...)