# How do I Transfer Bitcoins If I have a watch-only account with the Private Key

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, private-key, electrum, electron-cash

How do I transfer bitcoins over from a watch only electrum account if I have the private key and its address?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't spend Watch-Only coins, have I been scammed?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/95596/cant-spend-watch-only-coins-have-i-been-scammed)

Answer (score 2):

### Transfer control to a new Electrum wallet

If you have the private key you can, in principle, either *import* the key into a new wallet or *sweep* it into a new wallet.

Electrum supports [sweeping](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=sweep#can-i-sweep-private-keys-from-other-bitcoin-clients) and doesn't encourage [importing](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=sweep#can-i-import-private-keys-from-other-bitcoin-clients).

Importing doesn't involve a transaction or transaction fees but is more vulnerable to subsequent loss. The recovery-words also known as recovery-phrase or seed-phrase, cannot be used to recover control over money associated with an imported key. You'd need to make regular backups and test recovery from backup.

Sweeping involves a transaction but is regarded as safer.

---

### Transferring Bitcoins

Note that you are not really moving bitcoins. The record of who controls what money is recorded in the public Blockchain which every full-node wallet has a copy of.

A watch-only wallet lets you observe transactions relating to money controlled by other people (or by other wallets). So there's no sense in which your bitcoins are in a watch-only wallet. You could as well say that everyones bitcoins are in every full-node wallet.

---

### Electrum account

Electrum is a wallet, not an account. Your money is not stored by, managed by or controlled by Electrum.org. *You* control your money using software you install on your own computer.

---

### Watch-only

Watch-only wallets are a useful feature if you keep your private-keys in cold-storage - such as in a hardware wallet.

They are also a favourite method by which scammers trick people out of money.

Comment: +1 but I think the last part is the only relevant part.

Comment: I have one address in my wallet and one private key in a WIF format. Do I need multiple keys to have my regular spending wallet?, cause I only have one address.

Comment: You only need the key that corresponds to that address.

Comment: My Private Key is in a WIF Format, when I put it in it doesn't want to go with my address. Its 51 characters long. Is there a converter from WIF to a regular private key?

Comment: See the last sentence of my answer and the comments by MCCCS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some of your comments:

> My Private Key is in a WIF Format, when I put it in it doesn't want to
>   go with my address.

It sounds as though your wallet could be importing the wrong address type (ie legacy vs p2sh-segwit vs bech32).

With Electrum you can import your WIF and specify the address type.

Electrum can import private keys using the console and the `importprivkey()` command.

If you want to import p2sh segwit (address starts with a 3):
`importprivkey('p2wpkh-p2sh:L5eaxGKPZZMnanjxDzBd82VaxnHAE6MmBojiEFAVTM9mWZEhMMqG')`

Import as native(bech32) segwit (address starts with bc1):
`importprivkey('p2wpkh:L5eaxGKPZZMnanjxDzBd82VaxnHAE6MmBojiEFAVTM9mWZEhMMqG')`

Import as legacy p2pkh (address starts with a 1):
`importprivkey('p2pkh:L5eaxGKPZZMnanjxDzBd82VaxnHAE6MmBojiEFAVTM9mWZEhMMqG')`